# PTIJ: What type of kavanah do I need in my PTIJ verbiage?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

When I ask Purim Torah questions, I also add proper verbiage so the people can understand me properly. However, recently I decided to add a keyboard shortcut that automatically adds the text with the click of a button. My concern however, is that the original *kavanah* that went into the meta posting has been lost.

And, based on the Talmudic dictum (Berachos 13a) כל פרשה צריכה כוונה, this would not be a valid posting. Especially based on the conclusion (ibid.) שמע מינה מצות צריכות כוונה. Which is likewise recorded in Orach Chaim 60:4.

> י"א שאין מצות צריכות כוונה וי"א שצריכות כוונה לצאת בעשיית אותה מצוה וכן הלכה:

After all this research, I have also started to question if one can even copy manually at all. Perhaps, one must type it out manually each time, as the Talmudic dictum goes (Kidushin 41a) מצוה בו יותר מבשלחו, better to do it yourself.

Additionally, since this is  the biblical commandment of Torah study I feel the need to be extra stringent.

The question thus stands, if I can continue using my shortcut at all, and if there is room to permit a general copying which most of the site is wont to do.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you do for this question? Did you type it out, or did you copy it?

Comment: Outsourced it to India

Comment: You certainly don't get credit for it if you got someone from India to do it for you.

Comment: @Don Oh don’t worry. It was done Leshem Kedushas Mi Yodeya.